# AngularJS Material date picker not alligned

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm having a button and angular js material date picker in a row. Date picker is not aligned correctly. I tried adding a margin too. Without using an additional CSS file ,(adding in line css) please help me to align these components.

```
  <div>
<md-button class="md-raised md-button job-export-jobs md-ink-ripple">Export Jobs Date</md-button>
<md-input-container>
  <label for="jobDate">Export date</label>
  <md-datepicker  
  ng-model="model.exportJobsDate">
  </md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`layout="row"`** and then **`flex`** by giving the distribution,

```
<div class='calendarDiv' layout="row">
    <div flex=40>
      <md-icon style="position:absolute;margin-top:15px; left:20px" md-svg-src="calendar.svg"></md-icon>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
    <div flex=60>
      <md-button class="md-raised md-button job-export-jobs md-ink-ripple">Export Jobs Date</md-button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/D6LWIlL5MeIqTU1ENp5U?p=preview)**